# CORS Error on Wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, cors, react-redux

I am a little confused about how to handle a wikipedia api call in react. I keep running into this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource(...)

Right now, I am running an action upon submitting a form, the form takes the form input value and inserts that into the Wikipedia api URL. I have tried using JSONP, but I really would prefer not to use that since I have heard it is super hacky.

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonp&list=search&titles=";
const FETCH_ARTICLES = 'FETCH_ARTICLES';

export function fetchArticles(term) {
  const url = `${WIKI_URL}${term}`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  return {
    type: FETCH_ARTICLES,
    payload: request
  }
```

I can definitely add more code if necessary, but from what I can tell, this is where the problem lies.

edit: If I had to use JSONP, I still have not been able to. I believe that axios does not support JSONP, would there be a better library to use? Why do some APIs have a Cross Origin Reference Error while others do not?

Comment: Looks like a few others are having the same problem https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/191

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drop `format=jsonp` and add `origin=*` to the query params in the WIKI_URL value:

```
const WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query…";
```

See [the CORS-related docs for the Wikipedia backend](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS#Description):

> For anonymous requests, `origin` query string parameter can be set to `*` which will allow requests from anywhere.

As far as the `format` param, JSON output is the default, so you don’t need to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get around this without using JSONP, the solution would be to have a proxy server which accepts your requests, and adds the proper CORS headers to the response. As a starting point, this will help as a reference: https://gist.github.com/pauloricardomg/7084524

Comment: I am hoping for a bit simpler solution than creating a proxy server. Why do some APIs cause this problem while others do not? From what I can tell, every time you reference an API, you are calling something that is not your domain

Comment: If the domain is "cross-origin", meaning the endpoint does not resolve to the domain which the script was served from; the browser makes an OPTIONS request to see if the current origin is allowed to make a certain request. If the API does not include your domain in the list of allowed origins, the browser will block the request. This is to prevent malicious clients apps from accessing resources which they should not be allowed to access.