# trying to access Wikipedia Api using axios but getting a CORS policy error

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, axios

Trying to access Wikipedia Api using axios and getting a CORS error.  I did some research and found this [article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283282/cors-error-on-wikipedia-api) .  Below is the code that I have:

```
let axiosData = function(){
let searchString = $('#searchString').val();
console.log(searchString);
let Url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ searchString + 
"&origin=&callback=";
axios.get(Url)
 .then(function(res){
     console.log(res);
 })
 .catch(function(){
     console.log("Error")
 });
return false;
 }

$('form').submit(axiosData);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you add "origin=*" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must send either your domain or a wildcard * in the origin parameter.

Like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=testing&origin=*&callback=
```